# How do entities in relationship know what to join on

Tags: ios, core-data

This is a basic question from someone transitioning from SQL-based databases that I normally sweep under the carpet but would really like to understand.  When two entities are joined in a relationship, how does Core Data figure out what attribute to join on?  Does it figure it out by matching attribute names, or just how does it know?

I'm asking to understand why following code is not working.

I have one entity, Books with attributes as follows:

```
aid|authorname
```

I have another entity, Authors with attributes

```
bid|bookname|authorid

//note authorid here is spelled differently than in the author entity.
```

Authors has a Many relationship to Books named book
Books has One relationship to Authors named author.

In the books VC, in the .h file I have

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) Books * book;
```

In the .m file I have following code in ViewDidLoad

```
NSString *authorname = self.book.author.authorname;
//this is supposed to be book-object.author-relationship,authorname-attribute
//however it displays blank
NSLog(@"author name%@",authorname); //displays blank
```

I have very similar code working elsewhere in the app that works fine (though both relationships are one-to-one) so I think I must be missing something dumb somewhere.

However, it has prompted me to wonder exactly how does core-data figure out which author goes with which books?

Are the attribute names supposed to match up?

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: You know that you don't need to have id fields for your Core Data Entities? Also, you don't need to add the id's as attributes -> these are handled by relationships.

Comment: Yes.  my ids are for interacting with a server and I realize there are automatically generated managed object ids.  However, I still don't understand how Core Data matches object ids in one entity to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreData "knows" that two objects are related if and only if you tell it, which you do by (assuming you have defined the relationship in the data model editor) assigning one object to the relationship property of the other object:

```
myBook.author = myAuthor;
```

or equivalently

```
[myAuthor addBooksObject:myBook];
```

Once you've done that, CoreData will "know" that those two objects are related (even if you save the data then reload it).  This is completely independent of the attributes (such as `aid` and `authorid`) that you might think indicate that two objects are related.

If you want `Books` to be related to the `Author` with `aid` equal to the Book's `authorid`, you have program it that way.  So, if for example you sync an `Author` from your server, with `aid = 123`, and then sync some `Books` with `authorid = 123`, you will need to fetch (unless you already have a reference to it) the `Author` with `aid = 123`, and set the relationship with code similar to the above.  I suspect it is this step which you have missed, and is causing the blank author name.

If you do this during your sync process, you can thereafter just rely on the relationship, with no need to worry about primary keys, foreign keys, joins, etc.  Behind the scenes, CoreData maintains a unique primary key for each entity, and foreign keys for each relationship.  You can see these if you directly inspect the underlying SQLite database, and/or if you activate SQLDebug.

Comment: At what point in the sync process do you typically call myBook.author = myAuthor;?   When syncing books, I save a my book in the managed object context for each book..  Then I create a new author entity and save the author in it.  Is this where I would include myBook.author = myAuthor;?

Comment: @zztop  The optimum sequence will depend on the way the data is laid out by your server when you sync.  If possible, I would create the `Author` first, then loop through creating all the `Book`s and setting the relationship to the author you just created.  You might have to try to fetch the author first (using a predicate to get the one with the right `aid`) - if none are found then create a new one.  It is critical that, when you try to set the relationship, both objects must belong to the same managed object context.

Comment: So just to be clear, once you assign Hardy.book = Tess of the d'Urbervilles, core data remembers this for ever after?  But you have to loop through every book and author to wire these connections? i.e. Hardy.book = Far From the Madding Crowd, Hardy.book = Return of the Native, Dickens.book = David Copperfield etc.

Comment: @zztop Yes, exactly - provided you save the context in which you set the relationships.  Though because the `book` relationship is to-many, you would either do `[dickens addBookObject:DavidCopperfield]` or `davidCopperfield.author = dickens` etc